# discover if mod_rewrite is working (MAMP + codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I'm experimenting (and having problems!) with codeigniter.

In particular, links do not work.
even if they are correct (eg. http://localhost/ci-book/welcome/cat/3, where welcome is controller, cat the method), they can't be open and chrome says "Oops! This link appears to be broken...."

Someone suggested to check that mod_rewrite is working. How can I do that?

I'm using Mamp.

thanks,
P.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the basic URL without mod_rewrite works: http://localhost/ci-book/index.php?welcome/cat/3

Then setup mod_rewrite, restart httpd, and attempt to navigate back to your URL. If it works (or at least, if part of the page loads with errors), then mod_rewrite is working.